# Como copiar contenido de un XML de internet en XML local? en Android Studio con Java

Tags: java, android, xml

¿Como podria copiar el contenido de archivo XML de internet al archivo local del proyecto personas.xml en res/raw ?

Accedo al archivo almacenado en firebase, en enlace de que imprime el metodo onSuccess(Uri uri) es el correcto.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
public void leerXMLtoDocument() {

    // Create a storage reference from our app
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();


    storageRef.child("/personas.xml").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::Archivo conseguido");
            System.out.println(uri);
            File fileDoc = new File(uri.getPath());

        }


    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::Archivo NO conseguido");
        }
    });
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente lo descargas y lo almacenas en una ruta específica?

Comment: Estuve probando tambien pero no sabia como descargarlo. Si me puedes ayudar

Comment: ¿Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613007/download-and-parse-xml-file-from-firebase) te sirve?

Comment: Sí que accede al archivo de Firebase pero no puedo elegir el directorio donde almacenarlo, voy a preguntar en la respuesta. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Mediante la clase [FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot?hl=es-419)  puedes realizar lo que deseas, pero en este caso debes usar como referencia la url del "bucket" donde se encuentra el archivo que deseas descargar,

```
    // Create a storage reference from our app
    //StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("<url_bucket>");
```

revisa este ejemplo basado en el de [**@Stephenraj**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40859137/250260)

```
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("<your_bucket>");
    StorageReference  islandRef = storageRef.child("personas.xml");

    //File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "personas.xml");
    File rootPath = getExternalFilesDir("personas.xml");

    if(!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    }

    final File localFile = new File(rootPath,"personas.xml");

    islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
          //Archivo creado exitosamente.               
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            //Error al crear archivo.
        }
    });
```